# Do rich companies pay little/no corporate income taxes in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes

It's a fairly common "fact" that if you make enough money, that you can hire lawyers who can hide all of your money, so that you end up paying little to no tax. Is this true?

Comment: I am pretty sure that "*no* taxes" is an exaggeration :)

Comment: @Largerbaer: Okay then, I'll change it to be little/no

Comment: @Lagerbaer: Actually, it *is* commonly claimed that many/most/the biggest companies in America do indeed pay *no* taxes whatsoever. Whether the claim is an exaggeration or not (and I'm as interested in the answer to this question as the OP), the question doesn't exaggerate the claim :-)

Comment: By European standards, they'd pay "next to no taxes" even if they'd pay their taxes :-P

Comment: Unless a US company is able to forgo paying payroll taxes then it is impossible for them to pay no tax.  I know of no such exemption for any company.  You should probably reword your question to address corporate income tax.

Comment: @Lagerbaer - I'm sorry but you are 100% wrong. See my answer to the question inspired by your comment - http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/do-us-companies-pay-significantly-less-taxes-than-european-ones-based-on-tax-rat/2135#2135

Comment: I'm sure there are companies trying to get away with tax fraud (in fact my father, who was a tax auditor before retiring, regularly got questions from customers on how to do just that, he always refused to help them). I'm also reasonably sure some of them might sneak under the radar for a year or more before they're caught at it, but I doubt that would apply to any "rich" company (unless you class any company as "rich" that makes more money than a few thousand dollars in profit) and not be subject to serious scrutiny by tax collectors.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, **some** "rich" (meaning big and usually multinational) companies pay taxes that are significantly lower than predicted by their theoretical income tax rate for their income bracket. Examples include (from [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/2010/04/01/ge-exxon-walmart-business-washington-corporate-taxes.html)):

- The most egregious example is General Electric ( GE - news - people ). Last year the conglomerate generated **$10.3 billion in pretax income**, but ended up owing nothing to Uncle Sam. In fact, it recorded a tax benefit of $1.1 billion.... In 2008 GE's effective tax rate was 5.3%; in 2007 it was 15%. The marginal U.S. corporate rate is 35%.
- Valero was zero. One can be tempted to spin a conspiracy theory out of that one...
- Verizon's was 10.5%
- HP's rate was 18.6%. Not zero, but not 35% either.
- IBM was 25%, Procter & Gamble 26.3%
- Boeing was 23% (due R&D credits, mostly)
- Several more companies (Bank of America, Citibank, Ford) on Forbes's list in the article has very low rates explicitly related to gigantic losses in the last couple of years.
- However a vast majority of the rest of the list (25 top US companies as Forbses titled it) was in close-to-maximum 30+% range, with the usual tax-loving-people's favorite whipping boys (oil companies) rates in 40+%.

---

As far as the explanation of how that happens, an income tax code contains an enormous amount of ways for a large multinational to reduce taxes owed.

Among the most impactful general principles as far as this question are the ones dealing with:

- [Carryforward of past losses](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/losscarryforward.asp). In GE's specific case, it was large losses in its financial subsidiary during the bank meltdowns and writing off the fact that they closed 20 US factories between 2007 and 2009.
- assorted accounting rules allowing you to time-shift profits (see the discussion of cash vs. accrual basis [here](http://www.referenceforbusiness.com/small/A-Bo/Accounting-Methods.html)) to whenever you will pay the least amount of taxes.
- Geographical shifting - e.g. accounting so that your profits are earned outside of USA (offshore). The article linked in another answer posits that this provided a large portion of tax savings, though it didn't document that statement.

  A very detailed laymans-terms explanation is in this Bloomberg article: "[Google 2.4% Rate Shows How $60 Billion Lost to Tax Loopholes](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2010-10-21/google-2-4-rate-shows-how-60-billion-u-s-revenue-lost-to-tax-loopholes.html)"
- numerous other loopholes and deductions to pay less taxes. This is due to two factors:

  - the influence of lobbyists on politicians who write the tax-affecting laws.

    As an example, "GE became the nation's top corporate spender on lobbying, spending more than $238 million on lobbyists over the past 12 years, according to the Center for Responsive Politics" ([ABC news](http://abcnews.go.com/Blotter/ge-top-corporate-spender-lobbying/story?id=13087750)).

    To back the article up, here's the hard #s for lobbying: 2008 - $18 million; 2009 - $26.4mm, 2010 - about $40mm (source: http://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/clientsum.php?year=2010&lname=General+Electric). Obviously, not all lobbying money relates to tax code, but it's hard to imagine that some of it doesn't influence it in some ways, sometime via specific regulation that changes how tax code could be applied (e.g. what is considered "clean" technology).

    And for political contributions: In 2010, GEPAC raised just over $1.4 million from more than 4,000 employees and contributed $1,276,950 to federal and $126,250 to state candidates in the United States ([GE's own data](http://www.ge.com/citizenship/our-priorities/public-policy/political-contributions.html)). Non-GE numbers come [from opensecrets](http://www.opensecrets.org/pacs/lookup2.php?cycle=2008&strID=C00024869) (Center for Responsible Politics) again: $2.5mm in 2010 and a whopping $3.6mm in total political donations in 2008.
  - the fact that US government uses taxes as an instrument of social control (e.g. tax deductions for "clean" technology consumption AND capital investment, both of which GE can play). This factor is of course related to lobbying one above.

Comment: Does this even answer the question?

Comment: @ProdigySim - based on the fact that the OP accepted the answer, I would venture to guess that it does.

Comment: Based on the subjectline, "Do Rich companies ...?" I think it doesn't. All this answer shows is that there are methods that _can_ lead to the end, not really that any companies _do_ ever each that end.

Comment: @Prodigysim - Oh, I see what you mean. I added actual examples to the answer - I sort of assumed the question of "Do?" was rhethorical and based off of reports of GE so no example was needed.

Comment: Good edit. I think the idea of a "rhetorical" question kind of defeats the purpose of skeptics.

Comment: I'm calling BS on your statement about oil companies paying high taxes.  You (or Forbes, a notorious corporate apologist) have cherry-picked data from an unusual year, (e.g. Exxon 2009).  Exxon had unusually low profits in 2009 (gee, can't remember why that would have been).  In the surrounding years, they've had much more net income, and paid much lower tax rates. [Source](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2013/04/27/do-oil-companies-pay-enough-in-taxes-or-too-much.aspx#lastVisibleParagraph) ... I took it easy on you, and even found another corporate apologist source to refute you.

Comment: @Nate - having trouble with reading comprehension, or having trouble with NOT cherrypicking a # out of that article that the whole article basically debunks as a meaningless one? The article shows **effective tax rate on Exxon in 2012 as 39.4%** . BTW, if you read Forbes article carefully, their #s also show effective tax rate. For ALL companies being compared, not just Exxon.

Comment: @Nate -  Quoting from Fool's article's conclusion: "The thing about numbers is that they can be easily presented in a way that gives credence to any argument, and any fact or truth can be produced to back up a claim. Do big oil companies like Exxon pay considerably lower U.S. income taxes than individuals? Yes. **But do they pay a high tax rate that would seem unfair to other sectors? Yes.** "

Comment: @KVM, you may be interpreting it as "meaningless".  I have no problem reading numbers and assessing their meaning.  The 39.4% number was not from the Fool's analysis, but simply quoted without explanation from S&P Capital IQ.  I'd love an explanation of that math, given the other data on the page.  What I see in the Fool's analysis are numbers anywhere between 3.5% and 14%, depending on what you consider a "tax".  That includes money for the spill cleanup fund.  Most people would call that "insurance".  It also attempts to include royalties for oil taken from public lands.

Comment: Most people would call that a "rent".  When gas companies pay private landowners to frack on their property, that's not considered a "tax".  It's easy to think taxes are high when you stretch the meaning of all your costs to be "taxes".  But still, that only brings the number to 14%.  If you're going to stick by the 39.4% number, please elaborate.  Then, there's the Forbes byline that says *"I'm based in Houston, Texas. Energy capital of the world."* You could not possibly be any lazier in finding an unbiased source.

Comment: If you'd like, I could quote you numbers from some place like treehugger.com that subtracts subsidies for oil/gas exploration, the externalities of pollution, or the cost to preserve access to oil with our military.  That would be about as objective as you quoting finance rags that term everything a "tax". Finally, there's the statement *"a vast majority of the rest ... was in close-to-maximum 30+% range"*.  That's **extremely** disingenuous considering the average effective rate for US companies is historically about 24%.

Comment: @Nate - when something the size of GE, Google and Apple is close to zero, the math easily works out to majority of the rest being way closer to 30 than 240%. And the question was about taxes, not pollution. If you like, you can ask a different question. Like how much pollution an average environmental conference generates. Or why, if it's capitalism that causes all the pollution, all of you tree huggers haven't already moved to less capitalist country, like USSR, Cuba or China.

Comment: Stop moving the goalposts.  You didn't say "closer to 30".  You said *"close to maximum 30+% range"*.  I know the question wasn't about pollution.  It also wasn't about "insurance", and the title even specified "income tax", which is a subset of all taxes.  My point, that you obviously missed, is that to even get the effective rate of 14%, it required counting costs like the spill cleanup fund as a "tax".  I pointed out that I could get creative, too, and try to subtract gov't expenses from the tax bill, to make the tax rate look **lower**.  The gov't pays to clean up oil companies' pollution.

Comment: I would encourage you to ask how much pollution an environmental conference generates, on sustainability.stackexchange.com.  *"if it's capitalism that causes all the pollution..."*  Strawman.  When did I say that?  Also, the USSR is no longer a country, and even the countries that still exist in its place are not terribly good on environmental issues.  Other questions?

Comment: The trouble with comparing the headline rate of taxation to the effective rate is that the tax code of full of offsets and exemptions. The typical rate of 20-25% is not unusual given these rules. To conclude that this means companies pay "little or no" tax is absurd.

Answer (score 7):

***Two out of every three United States corporations paid no federal income taxes from 1998 through 2005**, according to a report released Tuesday by the Government Accountability Office, the investigative arm of Congress.*

...

***In 2005,** one in four large United States corporations paid no taxes on revenue of $1.1 trillion, **compared with 66 percent in the overall pool**.*

...

***In 2004,** a G.A.O. study said that 7 in 10 of all foreign corporations doing business in the United States, or foreign-controlled corporations, paid no taxes from 1996 through 2000, **compared with 6 in 10 United States corporations**.*

http://www.nytimes.com/2008/08/13/business/13tax.html?_r=1

The story also includes a quote from a fella from the Tax Foundation, an organization well-known to peddle corporate propaganda about taxes, about how the untaxed corporations are just simply the corporations that lost money, making no profit, and thus paying no taxes.  Although such examples certainly do exist, the statement is false, as is most everything that you hear out of the Tax Foundation.

[In fact, a NYTimes author, in a blog post](http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/08/24/the-tax-foundation-is-not-a-reliable-source/), linked a mash-up of articles rebuffing the Tax Foundation, and I found this in that mash-up:

***the actual tax rates paid by US corporations are extraordinarily low, around 6%.***

...

*Remember the latest GAO report (reported elsewhere on ataxingmatter) that shows that two-thirds of US corporations pay no federal income tax. That's not just the ones that are losing money, **but also many corporations that have record high profits (including some Big Oil companies) that end up paying next to nothing in taxes**.*

...

*As a result, the US is actually a corporate tax haven, with the lowest effective corporate tax rates of almost all the countries that participate in the OECD. That's a little fact that the Tax Foundation apparently doesn't want the American public to understand, since all its hype is in terms of statutory rates and not in terms of effective tax rates.*

http://economistsview.typepad.com/economistsview/2008/08/the-greek-menac.html

Just to give an example, one way to avoid paying corporate income tax is to provide goods & services, for pennies on the dollar, to a subsidiary operating in a foreign country that doesn't tax them.  By doing so, you erase your domestic profits by sending it to a foreign subsidiary in the form of goods & services, which they then use to make even larger profits, which they then send back to you, untaxed.

Comment: I haven't bothered analyzing the rest of your article for BS, but based on the quote regarding "but also many corporations that have record high profits (including some Big Oil companies) that end up paying next to nothing in taxes", it doesn't look promising. If you bother looking at the data I linked in my answer, the oil companies in the sample paid the HIGHEST effective tax rate among 25 biggest US companies; 40+%, higher than top tax bracket. Also, a hint - if you don't want to sound like a crazed anti-capitalist, drop the derogatory "Big Oil" moniker.

Comment: Also, "Two out of every three United States corporations paid no federal income taxes from 1998 through 2005, according to a report released Tuesday by the Government Accountability Office, the investigative arm of Congress." - if you don't want to sound like a DNC propaganda arm, you might want to actually provide the analysis of the distribution of income brackets. You know, a "corporation" is not just GE. It's also a mom-and-pop small business - a LOT of which lose money or don't make too much of it.

Comment: "Although such examples certainly do exist, the statement is false, as is most everything that you hear out of the Tax Foundation." - unproven assertion. -1

Comment: @DVK The issue of mom-and-pop vs. fortune500-type corporations is address in the following quote: "*In 2005, **one in four large United States corporations** paid no taxes on revenue of $1.1 trillion, **compared with 66 percent in the overall pool.***"  As far as oil corps go, just because some of them paid substantial taxes, that doesn't mean all of them did, which is why the quote says "***SOME*** Big Oil companies."  I trust that you know what the definition of "some" means.

Comment: @Michael - CBO also added the ratio of 10% of large corporations in 2005 being **new** with the caveat that a new corporation usually doesn't HAVE positive income. So that dramatic figure of 25% all over the sudden becomes 15%. Subtract the companies that had losses due to high oil prices (such as airlines) as well as commodity prices (jumped 30% in 2005). You'd be lucky if left with 10%, probably large multinationals

Comment: @DVK Do you have anything to debunk the statements of Linda Beale (who has a rather impressive CV and is most certainly not a "hack reporter,") such as "6% effective tax rate," "lowest effective corporate tax rates of almost all the countries that participate in the OECD," or 2% for the US vs. a 3.5% average for OECD countries in terms of corporate tax liability in relation to GDP?

Comment: @Michael - I'm not interested in average effective tax rate **as it pertains to this question**.  Especially since the average (or, if you want to be a bit professional about it, **mean**) would be significantly influenced by just a few large outliers (GE *cough* *cough*). As far as Linda Beale, I don't dispute her qualifications, but I definitely dispute her motives and certainly dispute her objectivity. She's not a random tax professor reporting research #s. She's a person with extreme political views reporting the #s that support them. #s may be accurate, but I seriously doubt the context.

Comment: @Michael -  As far as USA being lower than OECD, that's not very surprising since most of the geo-income-transferring multinationals are in the USA.

Comment: @Michael - As far as the reporter, making the same caveat as my comment made about the real rate likely being at most 15% vs 25% would be the honest thing to do even without the CBO's exact breakdown, except he wanted to report the worst optics possible.

Comment: highly suggestive. You're linking different reports concluding that different companies in different years didn't pay some part of different taxes together to conclude that those companies paid no taxes whatsoever.

Comment: @jwenting Wrong.  No such implication was made, neither in my answer nor the linked articles.

Comment: @DVK, your comment criticizing the poster for using the moniker *"Big Oil"* is absurd in the context of you using the term *"tax-loving-people's"* in your answer.  Project much?

Comment: @Nate - touche as far as using derogatory-intended terminology. Except that my answer was backed up with data - especially the specific quip I made, while his specific quip was contradicted by it :)

Comment: @DVK, your answer had data about how many of us liberals actually *"love"* taxes?  Really?  I didn't see that part.  It just sounds like name-calling to me.  Furthermore, **Michael** did not make a quip about "Big Oil".  It was a quote from the article he linked to (from Linda Beale, who I'm assuming is not a "he").  That's what the *italic* font means.  And you're accusing me of having trouble with reading comprehension?  Seriously.

Comment: @DVK, and by the way, [this thread from Michael's answer](http://economistsview.typepad.com/economistsview/2008/08/the-greek-menac.html) does at least have a post from one reader (`bullbust`) that explains that to get to that 40% effective tax range, you need to include taxes paid to foreign countries, not just to the US.  That's kind of an important detail in the context of **this** question, and the size of the US/foreign tax payments.

Comment: IF you are going to makes claims based on a GAO report, you should at least reference a recent report. [Here is a quote from one recent example](https://www.gao.gov/products/GAO-16-363): "Over tax years 2008 to 2012, all large corporations—profitable and those that reported current year losses—paid 25.9 percent of their pretax net income in U.S. federal income taxes..." That's a better and more relevant answer than everything you wrote in yours.

Answer (score 4):

Stories like [General Electric Paid No Taxes In 2010](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/general-electric-paid-federal-taxes-2010/story?id=13224558) are common in America. I can remember reading similar stories over the years. It would be surprising if only GE pays no tax - otherwise, how would other giant companies compete with GE?

Comment: There's one key point of this, that does make alot of sense. 

In a statement, General Electric said that it "pays what it owes under the law and is scrupulous about its compliance with tax obligations in all jurisdictions." The company claims that its zero-dollar tax bill is largely a result of losses at its financial arm, GE Capital, due to the Wall Street meltdown.

Comment: regarding "how would other giant companies compete with GE", it's quite possible that GE got special waivers/specially worded tax provisions etc... inserted which benefit it better than competitors. The is done both via general lobbying of both partis as well as cosy relationships with specific highly placed individuals (GE chairman with current US administration, for example).

Comment: Well, yes! GE paid $N to lobby for preferential tax treatment, and then paid $N/M in tax. In the case of 2010 tax, they paid $0. Lobbying has an incredibly good return on investment, if your business is big enough in the first place.

Comment: It's also a question of WHICH tax didn't they pay, and why. GE pays taxes, as does pretty much everyone else, but they might have an excemption on some taxes or get subsidies and credits to the point where it cancels out some other taxes. For example a company may have to pay $100 million in corporate taxes but receive $110 million in subsidies. The anti-capitalists will claim they pay no taxes when in fact they do.

Comment: @jwenting, did you read the explanation of why GE paid no taxes?