# Is the average effective corporate tax rate in US only 15% in 2017?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I have seen plenty of arguments and articles claiming that companies pay significantly below statutory tax rates. This [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/eriksherman/2017/04/24/trumps-corporate-tax-slash-ignores-how-litte-companies-already-pay/#ff4ddf958aa3) claims that number was around 15%. But then I see articles like this [MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/does-corporate-america-need-a-tax-cut-heres-what-every-sp-500-company-actually-pays-in-taxes-2017-12-04) one that lets you see the effective taxes on S&P 500 companies, which shows a median effective tax rate at about 30%. This is a huge discrepancy.

Now obviously they will be using different methodology to skew the data favorably to their message, but which of these claims is *more right* in regards to the big picture in the US? Are companies in the US paying high or low taxes on average?

---

Note: [This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/do-rich-companies-pay-little-no-corporate-income-taxes-in-the-united-states) is related, but focus on the special case companies like GM that pay very little, and focuses on how they whittle the taxes down. I'm asking about the common claim of low effective corporate tax rate for the whole of the American Market. I'm not so interested in special cases, but more in averages and characteristics of taxes in the context of the potential upcoming tax bill in 2017.

Comment: Forbes links to its data source, the Government Accountability Office, which describes their data collection methods and analysis methods in detail. By contrast I am having a very hard time reading the MarketWatch article. I have no idea how they are calculating their rates. I can't tell if they are comparable to the tax rates calculated by the GAO or not.

Comment: @BobTheAverage they have this little footnote on MarketWatch, which is a start: "The median effective income-tax rate is calculated using data from the past 11 years of annual 10-K filings with the Securities and Exchange Commission. "

Comment: TBear I saw that. That description is completely insufficient.

Comment: Higher or lower than what?  Comparisons to European countries commonly fail to take into account the effects of VAT, which is equivalent to a corporate income tax.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I am a layman in Economics but I understand that VAT is paid by the end customer, so it should be neutral for corporate taxes.

Comment: @Miguel - That's what they want you to believe.  It's done that way so that the tax can be refunded for exports, providing a government subsidy.  But the tax is calculated on the company's net income, and passed along at each step in the wholesale process.

Comment: @DanielRHicks compared to "other" develeoped countries (which is another can of worms), but the arguments are that either our effective tax rates are competitive or they are not. If they are not, then US companies will do more business overseas (e.g. Singapore) and never repatriate the profits.

Comment: @DanielRHicks VAT is manifestly not a *corporate* tax. Unless all sales taxes are also corporate taxes, which is an absurd way to describe them.

Comment: @matt_black - If you look at how VAT is calculated (absent the usual exceptions), it is exactly the same as a corporate income tax -- calculated at each wholesale transfer vs on the retail price.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do rich companies pay little/no corporate income taxes in the United States?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/do-rich-companies-pay-little-no-corporate-income-taxes-in-the-united-states)

Comment: @DanielRHicks Well, no it isn't. VAT is calculated on value added not corporate profit. And they are far from the same, which is why unprofitable firms still have to pay their VAT bills. Firms *collect* VAT on behalf of government and the ultimate payer is the end-user not the corporation collecting the VAT. Corporation tax cares nothing of transfers only about the net profitability of all activities.

Comment: Forbes is claiming that the *average* (mean) rate is 15%, and MarketWatch is claiming that the *median* rate is 30%. There is no mathematical contradiction between those claims.  This is what you would see, for instance, if there were a few firms paying a much lower rate than the others (particularly if the average is weighted by firm size or income, which would be natural, and the low-tax firms are large).  It's not really sensible  to ask which of a mean and median is "more right"; they simply summarize the data in different ways.

Comment: @NateEldredge - That idea definitely aligns with the commonly stated point (that I don't have proof of at this point) that the huge corporations are the ones who lobbied to have these loopholes they can exploit, while smaller businesses have to pay a much higher rate, especially if "average rate" is averaged based on total revenues. That's why the completely implausible claim going into this tax rate cut was that it was going to be reform, not just a cut, with loopholes being closed in conjunction with the rate coming down. Have a bridge to sell to anyone who thought that was going to happen.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate.  The other question asks if there are individual companies that pay zero (or very little) tax.  This question says it doesn't care if there are.  It wants to know what the effective tax rate is across all companies.  They are related but not that similar.

Answer (score 10):

**There is a lot of confusion about effective tax rates but the consensus is that the effective rate in the USA is in the 20-25% range**

The trouble with almost any article that quotes an effective tax rate is that there as a lot of different ways to calculate it so there are rather too many ways to get the result you want other than a truly representative result.

There are many reasons why the headline number (35%) is not the same as the actual tax paid. The US code has vast number of deductions and allowances that allow corporations to write off certain types of expense. Overseas earnings are only taxable if repatriated.

For example, do you count all public corporations or just the profitable ones; do you count just big corporations or all sizes; do you count only multinationals or just domestic firms; do you count just federal taxes or all corporate taxes? These choices make big differences to the result.

The Forbes article quoted in the question quotes several different calculations but the most relevant to tax policy is for profitable large corporations and actually has a range from 20-25% (not 15% as the question quotes). The result is baes on analysis by the [Government Accountability Office](https://www.gao.gov/products/GAO-16-363) who explain some of the issues fairly clearly:

> In each year from 2006 to 2012, at least two-thirds of all active corporations had no federal income tax liability. Larger corporations were more likely to owe tax. Among large corporations (generally those with at least $10 million in assets) less than half—42.3 percent—paid no federal income tax in 2012. Of those large corporations whose financial statements reported a profit, 19.5 percent paid no federal income tax that year. Reasons why even profitable corporations may have paid no federal tax in a given year include the use of tax deductions for losses carried forward from prior years and tax incentives, such as depreciation allowances that are more generous in the federal tax code than those allowed for financial accounting purposes.
>
> These reasons also explain why corporate effective tax rates (ETR) can differ substantially from statutory tax rates. ETRs attempt to measure taxes paid as a proportion of economic income, while statutory rates indicate the amount of tax liability (before any credits) relative to taxable income...

The same report summarises the results:

> When foreign and state and local income taxes are included, the average ETR [for profitable large corporations] across all of those years increases to just over 22 percent.
>
> Over tax years 2008 to 2012, all large corporations—profitable and those that reported current year losses—paid 25.9 percent of their pretax net income in U.S. federal income taxes...

We can check whether these numbers seem reasonable by comparing them to the specific tax rates for single real firms. [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/insights/071816/how-do-apples-taxes-compare-other-tech-giants-aapl.asp) did this for tech giants in 2016 and found:

> Apple Inc. had an effective tax rate of 26.4% in 2015, 26.1% in 2014 and 26.2% in 2013. This was neither the highest nor the lowest among mega-cap technology companies based in the United States. Many factors can influence effective tax rates, but research and development tax credits and geographical profit mix are especially relevant for large tech firms.
>
> Alphabet Incorporated's rate was significantly lower, ranging from 16.8% to 21.1%. Intel Corporation's effective tax rate was also lower at 19.6% in 2015, 25.9% in 2014 and 23.7% in 2013. ... Microsoft Corporation's effective rate was highly variable, swinging from 21% in fiscal 2014 to 34% in fiscal 2015.

Note that effective tax rates can look higher when firms make overseas losses (Amazon's effective rates in the USA look really odd because of this). But the important point here is that the GAO estimates for large firms seem to be reasonably comparable to what the public accounts of some of these large firms actually report.

This suggests that the *meaningful* number to quote is somewhere between 20-25% as the GAO suggests.